# PyPy3 fails installing numpy

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, numpy

Basically when I call `pypy3 -m pip install numpy --user` I get thrown this lovely mess:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # noqa
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import HAS_TLS, is_url, path_to_url, url_to_path
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import indent_log
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/plistlib.py", line 279, in <module>
    _dateParser = re.compile(r"(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)(?:-(?P<month>\d\d)(?:-(?P<day>\d\d)(?:T(?P<hour>\d\d)(?::(?P<minute>\d\d)(?::(?P<second>\d\d))?)?)?)?)?Z", re.ASCII)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/re.py", line 224, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/re.py", line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_compile.py", line 540, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 829, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 778, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 778, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 778, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 493, in _parse
    subpattern = SubPattern(state)
  File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/sre_parse.py", line 107, in __init__
    if data is None:
KeyboardInterrupt
r392781@MR-THINKPAD:~$ pypy3 -m pip install numpy --user
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/6e/f00492653d0fdf6497a181a1c1d46bbea5a2383e7faf4c8ca6d6f3d2581d/numpy-1.14.5.zip (4.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.9MB 759kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/pypy3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-rtmpcqec --python-tag pp360:
  Running from numpy source directory.
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmp0gbyfpzs/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmp0gbyfpzs/tmp/tmp0gbyfpzs
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp0gbyfpzs/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmp0gbyfpzs/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpm97xxqid/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpm97xxqid/tmp/tmpm97xxqid
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpm97xxqid/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpm97xxqid/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpiygihrzk/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpiygihrzk/tmp/tmpiygihrzk
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpiygihrzk/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpiygihrzk/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmp2g2vb_08/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmp2g2vb_08/tmp/tmp2g2vb_08
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp2g2vb_08/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmp2g2vb_08/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpc5m71stl/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpc5m71stl/tmp/tmpc5m71stl
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpc5m71stl/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpc5m71stl/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpr8whjs6j/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpr8whjs6j/tmp/tmpr8whjs6j
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpr8whjs6j/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpr8whjs6j/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpsew73n13/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpsew73n13/tmp/tmpsew73n13
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpsew73n13/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpsew73n13/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmponl3vq9x/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmponl3vq9x/tmp/tmponl3vq9x
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmponl3vq9x/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmponl3vq9x/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpqq8njrpu/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpqq8njrpu/tmp/tmpqq8njrpu
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpqq8njrpu/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpqq8njrpu/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
  non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
  /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
  F2PY Version 2
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpao6u0_98/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpao6u0_98/tmp/tmpao6u0_98
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpao6u0_98/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpao6u0_98/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpllk7ue4z/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpllk7ue4z/tmp/tmpllk7ue4z
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpllk7ue4z/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpllk7ue4z/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmps_1ll0gt/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmps_1ll0gt/tmp/tmps_1ll0gt
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmps_1ll0gt/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmps_1ll0gt/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpnnkq0tlb/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpnnkq0tlb/tmp/tmpnnkq0tlb
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpnnkq0tlb/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpnnkq0tlb/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpugdovrgj/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpugdovrgj/tmp/tmpugdovrgj
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpugdovrgj/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpugdovrgj/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpvl4m18ve/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpvl4m18ve/tmp/tmpvl4m18ve
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpvl4m18ve/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpvl4m18ve/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpifoz6px6/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpifoz6px6/tmp/tmpifoz6px6
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpifoz6px6/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpifoz6px6/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpt29izu7f/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpt29izu7f/tmp/tmpt29izu7f
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpt29izu7f/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpt29izu7f/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmptui2ez7i/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmptui2ez7i/tmp/tmptui2ez7i
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmptui2ez7i/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmptui2ez7i/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmprbn706th/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmprbn706th/tmp/tmprbn706th
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmprbn706th/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmprbn706th/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpf6r0h1jq/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpf6r0h1jq/tmp/tmpf6r0h1jq
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpf6r0h1jq/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpf6r0h1jq/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmp0tlhim9z/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmp0tlhim9z/tmp/tmp0tlhim9z
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp0tlhim9z/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmp0tlhim9z/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpntp75rgc/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpntp75rgc/tmp/tmpntp75rgc
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpntp75rgc/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpntp75rgc/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmphc0j0o1q/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmphc0j0o1q/tmp/tmphc0j0o1q
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmphc0j0o1q/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmphc0j0o1q/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmp120uasnp/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmp120uasnp/tmp/tmp120uasnp
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp120uasnp/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmp120uasnp/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmp7b07czgg/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmp7b07czgg/tmp/tmp7b07czgg
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp7b07czgg/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmp7b07czgg/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpjzsp10js/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpjzsp10js/tmp/tmpjzsp10js
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpjzsp10js/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpjzsp10js/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpny_lxu2u/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpny_lxu2u/tmp/tmpny_lxu2u
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpny_lxu2u/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpny_lxu2u/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpatv6_y4u/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpatv6_y4u/tmp/tmpatv6_y4u
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpatv6_y4u/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpatv6_y4u/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmprargolyu/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmprargolyu/tmp/tmprargolyu
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmprargolyu/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmprargolyu/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpcdlgt0ti/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpcdlgt0ti/tmp/tmpcdlgt0ti
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpcdlgt0ti/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmpcdlgt0ti/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmphytscc3u/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmphytscc3u/tmp/tmphytscc3u
  compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmphytscc3u/file.c.d -c'
  cc: /tmp/tmphytscc3u/file.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy
  creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.5/numpy/distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'intel', 'lahey', 'pg', 'absoft', 'nag', 'vast', 'compaq', 'intele', 'intelem', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pathf95', 'nagfor']'
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize IntelFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifc
  customize LaheyFCompiler
  Could not locate executable lf95
  customize PGroupFCompiler
  Could not locate executable pgfortran
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize NAGFCompiler
  customize VastFCompiler
  customize CompaqFCompiler
  Could not locate executable fort
  customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize PathScaleFCompiler
  Could not locate executable pathf95
  customize NAGFORCompiler
  Could not locate executable nagfor
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
  C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

  compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/opt/pypy3/include -c'
  cc: _configtest.c
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  /bin/bash: cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/setup.py", line 394, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/setup.py", line 386, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 131, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
      old_build.run(self)
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/pypy3/lib-python/3/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
      self.build_sources()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
      self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
      sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
      source = func(extension, build_dir)
    File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
      raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
  RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/pypy3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Running from numpy source directory.

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
Failed to build numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/pypy3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-8pnw1818/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-imqs6g4k/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /tmp/tmppm47lllt/tmp
    creating /tmp/tmppm47lllt/tmp/tmppm47lllt
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmppm47lllt/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /tmp/tmppm47lllt/file.c
    /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    /bin/bash: cc: command not found
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    C compiler: cc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC

    creating /tmp/tmp585jjn9u/tmp
    creating /tmp/tmp585jjn9u/tmp/tmp585jjn9u
    compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp585jjn9u/file.c.d -c'
    cc: /tmp/tmp585jjn9u/file.c
    /bin/bash: cc: command not found
    /bin/bash: cc: command not found
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    ...
    ...
```

I wasn't able to paste everything because it's so goddamn long

Anyway, I have the latest version of PyPy 6.0.0 and the latest version of pip 10.0.1.  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 as Windows Subsystem for Linux.

One thing I noticed is that the pip I run is actually located within python3.5.  The thing is, I used the `get-pip.py` file straight from PyPy's website to install pip for PyPy.

Here's the version info:

```
  pypy3 -m pip -V
  pip 10.0.1 from /home/r392781/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

I think I've tried everything from a bunch of different sites, but still nothing.  Kind of at my wits end here.

One last thing, numpy installs just fine when using `python3` instead of `pypy3`.

I'm not sure if this is relevant since this is Ubuntu exchange, but I have PyPy3 and pip installed on windows.  In this case, pip IS installed separately in a pypy3 directory BUT when I try to install numpy, I get thrown the same massive errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your issue seems to be from compiling from source, the same error probably would not occur if you installed a binary wheel of numpy to PyPy3

To do this, run the following command

`pypy3 -m pip install --extra-index https://antocuni.github.io/pypy-wheels/ubuntu cpython numpy`

pypy-wheels is a repository of precompiled wheels of some packages such as `numpy`

---

Sidenote:

PyPy has it's [own fork of NumPy called NumPyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy) and is unsupported on PyPy3 at the moment. Taking an excerpt from the repo:

> For now, NumPyPy does not work with PyPy3*, and is not complete. You
>   may get warnings or NotImplemented errors. Please let us know if you
>   get crashes or wrong results.

Therefore it's recommended that you install [PyPy2.7](https://pypy.org/download.html) for the moment as it has support for NumPyPy

Comment: Yes, but they also say that NumPy works with any current PyPy distribution.   Oddly enough they also say pip comes with PyPy which after two separate installs I can say that it doesn't and I had to manually get it every time.

Comment: @392781 Mind sharing the source of your information?

Comment: It's on PyPy's download page.  They recommend installing numpy through pip there.  As for pip not being included, that's more my case + a handful of people online that also had to install it manually to work with PyPy

Comment: @392781 I've edited the answer, can you please try that?

Comment: Alright, I gave it a shot.  First I tried exactly what you pasted and it threw a message saying that "No matching distribution found for cpython".  So then I tried without the cpython part and got the message saying that "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/.../python3.5/site-packages".  So now the issue is that PyPy is using pip that's installed with the python3.5 installation for some reason.  Anyway, when I try to import numpy in pypy3, I get yet another error saying "ImportError: ... Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy."

Comment: @392781 If you don't mind purging your wsl installation and starting fresh. Just do so and set up just `pypy` and `numpy` initially, the proceed to set up `python3`.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot.  python3 comes preinstalled with the WSL installation though.  Still, shouldn't do any harm to retry.  I'll do so in the morning and update you on it.

Comment: I wonder if this is still a safe option with today's versions, [while encountering something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936108/using-pip-in-a-venv-for-running-under-pypy)

Answer (score 0):

From http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-pypy3-2.4.0.html it says

```
NumPy which requires installation of our fork of upstream numpy, available on bitbucket
```

So you may try

```
sudo pypy -m pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git
```

Comment: This claims to be "historical release notes" and is out of date.  User mattip on freenode#pypy says that's out of date and standard fork numpy is fine these days.